# Sybase Error Implicit Conversion from datatype 'VARCHAR' to 'INT' not allowed

Tags: hibernate, int, sybase, varchar

I'm getting this error when trying to run a query in my application and I'm not sure why:

```
Caused by: com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybSQLException: Implicit conversion from datatype 'VARCHAR' to 'INT' is not allowed.  Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

at com.sybase.jdbc3.tds.Tds.a(Unknown Source)
at com.sybase.jdbc3.tds.Tds.nextResult(Unknown Source)
at com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.ResultGetter.nextResult(Unknown Source)
at com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybStatement.nextResult(Unknown Source)
at com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybStatement.nextResult(Unknown Source)
at com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybStatement.queryLoop(Unknown Source)
at com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
at com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybPreparedStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcPreparedStatement.executeQuery(WSJdbcPreparedStatement.java:678)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:208)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1953)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:802)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2533)
... 79 more
```

No where in my code am I trying to convert a VARCHAR into an INT.

Database View Columns  --> Java type:

```
INT --> Integer
VARCHAR --> String
INT --> Long
VARCHAR --> a POJO
FLOAT --> Double
DATE --> Date
```

Is there anything else that may cause this error??

Comment: Put the query and some code please.

Answer (score 1):

Implicit conversion from datatype 'VARCHAR' to 'INT' will occur when you fail to enclose a VARCHAR value in quotes.

Implicit conversion from datatype 'INT' to 'VARCHAR' will occur when you enclose an INT value in quotes.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the default values provided for few INT columns in the table definition had VARCHAR values.

Example :

jobCount INT DEFAULT '0'

Answer (score 0):

@user1505078 is correct

In this C code, I use DB-Library DBSMALLINT type to search into a VARCHAR column, the return type is also an Integer so I had to wrap %d with single quotes (i.e. '% d'). That was enough to "convert" the value, since whatever it is going between quotes in that query will be CHAR anyway.

```
DBSMALLINT region_code;  

dbbind(dbproc, 1, SMALLBIND, (DBINT)0, (BYTE *)&region_code); /* Integer */

sybase_error = False;
    dbfcmd(dbproc, "insert into <table_name> ");
    dbfcmd(dbproc, "select * from <another_table> ");
    /* With quotes, the query searches for Chars instead */
    dbfcmd(dbproc, "where group_code = '%d' ", region_code); /* Quotes in '%d' */
    dbsqlexec(dbproc);
    while (dbresults(dbproc) != NO_MORE_RESULTS)
      continue;
```