# Converting explicitly, but get "Implicit conversion from datatype 'VARCHAR' to 'INT' not allowed"

Tags: sybase

Just like the poster in this question ([Sybase Error Implicit Conversion from datatype 'VARCHAR' to 'INT' not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9541117/sybase-error-implicit-conversion-from-datatype-varchar-to-int-not-allowed)), I have a script that is explicitly converting all chars to ints before attempting to store them. In fact, the script runs perfectly on the test Sybase server. But when I run it in producation, I get the dreaded error:

```
Implicit conversion from datatype 'VARCHAR' to 'INT' is not allowed.  Use the CONVERT function to run this query.
```

One complicating factor: I'm not able to run the script directly on the production server. I have to use an in-house utility that is intended to log all production updates for data security purposes. It's buggy, so the problem may be some edge case that my script triggers - in which case, I'll just give up and insert records manually. But I'd like to be sure there's not something obvious that I'm missing.

```
declare @Year int, @Bill_Run_No int
select @Year = 2015, @Bill_Run_No = 3501
-- Add a new year's worth of Bill_Run_Cntl records

declare @BegDate datetime, @EndDate datetime, @CurBillRunNo int, @MonthName varchar(3), @CurMonth int

/* Start with January and run for 12 months */
select @CurMonth = 1
while (@CurMonth < 13)
begin
    select @CurBillRunNo = @Bill_Run_No + @CurMonth - 1
    select @BegDate = CONVERT(datetime, convert(varchar, @Year) + '-' + convert(varchar, @CurMonth) + '-01')
    select @EndDate = DATEADD(MM, 1, @BegDate)
    select @MonthName = datename(MM, @BegDate)

    INSERT INTO REVDB..Bill_Run_Cntl
        (Bill_Run_No, Begin_Run_DtTm, End_Run_DtTm,
        Bill_Run_Desc,
        Bill_Period,
        Complete_Flag, Bill_Frequency, Bill_SW_Maint, Sales_Tax_Pass ) 
    select @CurBillRunNo, @BegDate, @EndDate,
        @MonthName + ' ' + convert(varchar, @Year) + ' Monthly',
        convert(varchar, @Year) + RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(varchar, @CurMonth), 2),
        NULL, 'P', NULL, 'A'

    select @CurMonth = @CurMonth + 1
end
```

Edit: By request, here is the relevant part of the table definition. The * fields allow nulls.

```
Column_name        Type        Length
Bill_Run_No        int             4
Begin_Run_DtTm     datetime        8
End_Run_DtTm       datetime        8
Bill_Run_Desc      char           30
Bill_Period        char            6
Complete_Flag*     char            1
Bill_Frequency*    char            1
Bill_SW_Maint*     smallint        2
Sales_Tax_Pass*    char            1
```

Comment: Can you share the table design?

Comment: I'll grab it when I'm back at work. Maybe you'll catch something I missed.

Comment: Table design added to post.

Comment: I'd vote on your production security process doing something screwy. The code ran fine on our 15.7 ASE system.